# Is it possible to use "WHERE" clause to select all records in SQL Statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

Good Evening, I am curious if it is possible to make a WHERE-clause in a SQL statement which can show all records?

Below some explanation:

> Random SQL Statement (**Java**)-(**JSP example**), Normal Situation

```
String SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM table_example WHERE First_Col = '<%=passVar%>' ";
db.query(SqlStatement );
//........
//........
```

What if the **passVar** is 'ALL', and we need to prompt all the records out when **passVar** = All? I know I can do it with if-else and check if the **passVar** is "ALL" then query the **without-WHERE statement** to make it work..

> ```
> **without-WHERE statement (Java)-(JSP example)**
> ```

```
if(<%=passVar%> == "ALL") {
   SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM table_example";
} else {

   SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM table_example WHERE First_Col = '<%=passVar%>' ";
}
```

but can I just code one SQL statement to make all the records prompt? Something like below:

> (**Java**)-(**JSP example**)

```
String ShowAll = "";
if(<%=passVar%> == "ALL") {
    ShowAll = *;

} else {
    ShowAll = <%=passVar%>;
}
SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM table_example WHERE First_Col = ShowAll ";
```

Comment: You still put scriptlet code in JSPs?  Database calls?  Terrible.

Comment: lol, i just can followed the rules in my company...
really sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also works:

```
WHERE columnname LIKE '%'
```

Except for NULL values.

Comment: Thanks, I will try on it...
Just to verify that, if we make the columnname LIKE '%', whether it will retrieve data which start with ' ' (space)?

Comment: Yes, it will do that

Comment: Is there way to include NULL values too?

Answer (score 14):

Try with    `WHERE 1=1`::

```
Select * from myTable  WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: How can the OP insert that in the script to use only one query?

Answer (score 3):

where 1=1 worked for me, Although where clause was being used all records were selected.

You can also try

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID=CustomerID; /* query */
```

or 
[any_column_name]=[column_name_in_LHL]

(LHL=left hand side.)

copy the query and
[click here to try code](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to differ the 2 situations and make 2 queries out of it.

- If there is no where condition then the DB does not need to evaluate it (potencially faster)
- The source code/debugging output is clearer.

Comment: ya, currently I using two query...
but one of my friends has mentioned that, when the program getting larger/ bigger then it is better to find a ways to make one query instead of 2 or more, it's optional...
thanks...

Comment: You know - this made so much sense to me I completely stopped with this line of thinking and just made one more query.  The difference between a few extra lines of code and the nightmares of debugging a conditional query is a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving the special case inside the query itself, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table_example WHERE '<%=passVar%>' IN ('ALL', First_Col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with wildcard value `'%'` but I would recommend to use a Factory here to create the SQL statement, what you are trying to do smells a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Something else you could do, is making that combination of code and SQL a single query. Which means the IF..ELSE will be in SQL language.

Check these links for some more info:
[MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)
[Using If else in SQL Select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526592/using-if-else-in-sql-select-statement)

Answer (score -1):

On sqlserver you can make proc:

```
create proc select_all_on_null
@a int = null
as
begin
  select * from Records where (@a is null or Record_id=@a )
end
```

When you select be your program:

```
make @a in null will select all
```

if i is `number` there will select row with this id

Comment: This works for parameterized logic, thanks @bahaa