# How to get data from database with if clause (SQL query)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Suppose I have a table like the following:

```
Table name: trial

ID | Date        | Name | Status     | Type
1  | 2017-06-01  | ABC  | Not Active | Food
2  | 2017-06-02  | DEF  | Not Active | Food
3  | 2017-06-03  | GHI  | Active     | Food
```

To retrieve the last data with type = FOOD from the table above, I use this query

```
SELECT * FROM `trial` WHERE type = 'FOOD' order by id DESC limit 1
```

if I want to retrieve the latest data from type = FOOD, but if there the data with status = active, this data is taken.

Assuming the table conditions like this.

```
ID | Date        | Name | Status     | Type
1  | 2017-06-01  | ABC  | Active     | Food
2  | 2017-06-02  | DEF  | Not Active | Food
3  | 2017-06-03  | GHI  | Not Active | Food
```

I Use query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `trial` WHERE type = 'FOOD' AND status = 'ACTIVE' order by id DESC limit 1
```

But what if the table conditions change with this assumption.

```
ID | Date        | Name | Status     | Type
1  | 2017-06-01  | ABC  | Not Active | Food
2  | 2017-06-02  | DEF  | Not Active | Food
3  | 2017-06-03  | GHI  | Not Active | Food
```

How to retrieve the latest data from type = FOOD, but if there the data type = food with status is active, then use data with status = active, but if there is no active status then the last data use

What sql query should I use ?

Comment: select * from your_table where status='Active';

Comment: I want to take not only the active status only

Comment: Then go for a group by
  select * from your_table group by status

Comment: To select latest data from table where status is active you should use
`select * from your_table where status='Active' order by ID desc`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all results using where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682455/getting-all-results-using-where-clause)

Comment: *"Take the latest data from the status of the food type but if there is an active status of the type of food then the data taken is a line with active status. ... I want to take not only the active status only"* - I don't understand what *exactly* you're trying to do. Can product `ABC` (for instance) appear in this table multiple times with different statuses by date? What do you want to retrieve when the status is `Not Active` ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar If the data in my table is all active status, no data is displayed because you are using query where status = 'Active'. Whereas I want to retrieve the latest status data from the food type.

Comment: Is `ID` an auto-incremented PRIMARY key for this product status table or is it the product id (with the table using a compound PRIMARY key)?

Comment: @CD001 No, i only take 1 value only (limit (1)). With parameters as I described above.
Ya, ID is primary key & auto-incremen

Comment: @AdeKSetiadi please explain proper issue as per your question praveen's query work fine

Comment: @CD001 I have updated the question, hopefully can be understood my intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you want to take the latest data if there are all Not active, but if there is an active state you want those ?

Try this

```
Select * from your_table
WHERE Type = 'Food' 
ORDER BY Status != "Active" ASC, Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

or in Codeigniters Querybuilder

```
$this->db
    ->select("*")
    ->from("your_table")
    ->where("Type","Food")
    ->order_by("Status != 'Active'", "ASC")
    ->order_by("Date","DESC")
    ->limit(1);
```

Comment: I updated my question, sorry my previous question did not match what I mean

Comment: thats exactly what i showed you here - did you test it ? Because my query goes with that approach - if you have an active state - it would take it -
 otherwise it takes the latest entry

Answer (score 0):

first you study this manual [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44517548)..  this manual will help you to retrieve data from database.

you can fetch data from database using `select` command and `DESC` for latest record

```
select * from table_name where Status='Active' ORDER BY id DESC;;
```

Comment: I updated my question, sorry my previous question did not match what I mean

Answer (score 0):

select * from TabelName where status="Active"

Comment: I updated my question, sorry my previous question did not match what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Use where clause with ORDER BY :

```
select * from table_name where Status='Active' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: I updated my question, sorry my previous question did not match what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Please use below mentioned query.

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE Status='Active' AND Type='Food' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: I updated my question, sorry my previous question did not match what I mean

Answer (score 0):

```
 $where = array('status'=>'Active' ,'type' =>'Food');
 $this->db->where($where);
 $this->db->order_by('Date','ASC');
 $this->db->get('_table_name');
```

Comment: I updated my question, sorry my previous question did not match what I mean

Answer (score -1):

Try the following query

```
select * from table_name where Status='Active';
```